# Proving ${\rm dist}(f, L^{\perp}) := \sup\{ \langle f,x\rangle \mid \|x\| \leq 1, \; x \in L\}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $E$ be a normed space and let $L \subset E$ be a linear subspace. We put $$L^{\perp} := \{f \in E^{*} \mid \forall x \in L \; \langle f,x \rangle = 0 \}$$ Show that $${\rm dist}(f, L^{\perp}) := \sup\{ \langle f,x\rangle \mid ||x|| \leq 1, \; x \in L\}$$

Here I believe ${\rm dist}(f,L^{\perp})$ means the minimum of the set of distances from $f$ to $l \in L^{\perp}$

$\textbf{Theorem.}$ (Fenchel-Rockafeller). Let $\phi, \psi: E \to (-\infty, \infty]$ be two convex functions. Assume that there is some $x_0 \in D(\phi) \cap D(\psi)$ such that $\phi$ is continuous at $x_0$. Then, 
$$\begin{align*} 
\inf_{x \in E}\{\phi(x) + \psi(x)\} &= \sup_{x \in E^{\star}} \{-\phi^{\star}(-f) - \psi^{\star}(f)\}\\
&= \max_{f \in E^{\star}} \{-\phi^{\star}(-f) - \psi^{\star}(f)\}\\
&=-\min_{f\in E^{\star}} \{ \phi^{\star}(-f) + \psi^{\star}(f)\}
\end{align*}$$

where $\phi^{\star}(f) = \sup_{x \in E, \; f \in E^{\star}} \{ \langle f, x\rangle - \phi(x)\}$ is the "conjugate function".

Note that by definition, $E^{\star}$ is equipped with the operator norm. So that, $$||x|| := \sup_{||f|| \leq 1, f \in E^{\star}} \langle f,x \rangle, \; ||f|| := \sup_{||x|| \leq 1, x \in E} \langle f,x \rangle,$$
and $\langle f, x\rangle  = f(x)$ is called a dual pair and is not an inner product. We must show that $$\inf_{f \in E^{\star}} \{\phi(f) + \psi(f)\} = \sup_{x \in E} \{ - \phi^{*}(-x) - \psi^{\star}(x)\} = \sup_{||x|| \leq 1, \; x \in L}\langle f,x\rangle $$
So, $dist(f, L^{\perp}) = \inf_{f \in E^{\star}}\{||f - f_0|| \}, \; f_0 \in L^{\perp}$. Now we must define our functions $\phi$ and $\psi$.

Let $\phi(f) = ||f - f_0||$ and $\psi(f) = I_{k}(f) = \begin{cases} 
      0, & f\in L^{\perp} \\
      \infty, & f \not\in L^{\perp}
   \end{cases}$

Now we write out the conjugate functions $\phi^{\star}(f), \psi^{\star}(f): E^{\star} \to (-\infty, +\infty]$.

$$\phi^{\star}(f) = \sup_{f\in E^{\star}} \{ \langle f,x \rangle - ||f - f_0||\} = \sup_{f \in E^{\star}} \{\langle f, x \rangle - ||f|| \} + \langle f, f_0 \rangle =  \begin{cases} 
      \langle f, f_0 \rangle, & ||x|| \leq 1 \\
  \infty, & ||x|| > 1
   \end{cases}$$
and $$\psi^{\star}(f) = \sup_{f \in E^{\star}} \{ \langle f,x \rangle - I_{k}(f)\} = \begin{cases} 0, & x \in L \\
\infty, & x \not\in L\end{cases}$$
Now I apply the theorem and substitute $\phi(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ into $\sup_{E^{\star}} \{-\phi^{\star}(-f) - \psi^{\star}(f) \}$. We are only interested in functionals in $L^{\perp}$, so we consider only $x \in L$ and $||x|| \leq 1$. Hence, $$\sup_{f\in E^{\star}} \{-\phi^{\star}(-f) - \psi^{\star}(f) \} = \sup_{f \in E^{\star}, x \in L, ||x|| \leq 1} \{-\langle f,f_0\rangle - 0 \}$$

This isn't turning out to be what the exercise is asking me to show though. Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: I suspect there is a more straightforward approach.

Comment: @copper.hat Really? My approach is by directly applying the theorem which seems straightforward to me.

Comment: @tain: If it worked that would be fine. I have a more elementary approach below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is more straightforward that invoking Fenchel Rockafeller:

Let $\overline{B}$ be the closed unit ball.

Let $M= \sup_{x \in \overline{B} \cap L} |f(x)|$. Define $\phi(x) = f(x)$ for $x \in L$ and use the Hahn Banach theorem extend $\phi$ to all of $E$ in such a way that $\|\phi\| = M$. Note that $g = f-\phi \in L^\bot$. Then $\|f-g\| = \|\phi\| = M$, and hence
$\inf_{g \in L^\bot} \|f-g\| \le \sup_{x \in \overline{B} \cap L} |f(x)|$.

For the other direction, note that if $g \in L^\bot, x \in \overline{B} \cap L$ then
$\|f-g\| \ge |f(x)-g(x)| = |f(x)|$. Taking the $\sup$ of the right
hand side gives $\|f-g\| \ge M$, and hence
$\inf_{g \in L^\bot} \|f-g\| \ge M=\sup_{x \in \overline{B} \cap L} |f(x)|$.

Comment: Copper, thanks for answering. I am have some confusion about the definition of the norm now. Why are you allowed to say that $||\phi(x)|| = M$? I thought the norm was supposed to be how I define din my post. Are they equivalent?

Comment: I have $\|\phi\| = M$. I presume you are in a real space in which case they are the same norm. It is more typical to use $|f(x)|$ rather than $f(x)$.

Comment: I have this in my notes with regards to the norm: http://imgur.com/9puuMtM For your norm, $M$, to be equivalent to mind then $\langle f,x \rangle = |f(x)|$. Why is that true? i.e, why are the norms equivalent?

Comment: If $f$ is real valued and $A$ is symmetric about zero, then $\sup_{x \in A} f(x) = \sup_{x\in A} |f(x)|$. Is this what you are asking about? It is not that the norms are equivalent, these are just slightly different expressions for the same norm.

Comment: copper, I thought Relations on a set were symmetric, transitive, and/or reflective. So what does it mean when you say the set $A$ is symmetric about $0$? I do not see why what you said is true

Comment: You are losing me here, I mentioned nothing about relations. If the set $A$ satisfies the condition that if $x \in A$ then $-x \in A$ then you have the above.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.

Comment: Typically induced norms are defined with $|\cdot|$ then you have the same notation regardless of field.

Comment: I think my confusion comes from not knowing when we have certain norms. I'll make a separate post for that though.

Comment: There are two norms in my answer, one on $E^*$ which is the one you used, and implicitly I am using the same norm, but for functionals whose domain is restricted to $L$.

Comment: Hi again copper. When you wrote 'Note that $g = f - \phi \in L^{\perp}$', that is only for $x \in L$ correct?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. If $g \in L^\bot$, then $g \in E^*$ and $g(x) = 0$ for all $x \in L$. But it is defined on $E$. That was the point of the construction.

Comment: I was just confused on how you were defining $g$. But I think I get it now. You say let $g = f - \phi$. $g \in L^{\perp}$ for $x \in L$. Then $||f-g|| = ||\phi|| = M$ and hence the conclusion.

Comment: First I define $\phi$ on $L$ and then use Hahn Banach to extend it to all of $E$ while preserving the norm of $\phi$ on $L$. This is the main point. Then I define $g=f-\phi$ **everywhere**. I don't understand what you mean by $g \in L^\bot$ for $x \in L$. If $g \in L^\bot$ then $g$ is defined on **all** of $E$, not just $L$. We have $g(x) = 0$ for $x \in L$.